# makefile error for c++

Tags: c++

What is this error

```
:!make
g++ -g -I../direc1 -I./ -c final.cpp   
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [final.o] Error 127
```

?

Comment: Apparently you don't have g++ installed, or your `PATH` environment variable is not set up correctly.

Comment: I don't recognise that command prompt `:`... what operating system are you using?

Comment: Hazard a guess... You are running make from inside of vim. Vim may not read in your shell's config files since it loads a non interactive shell by default. This means your path could be different from inside vim and outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have g++ installed (or it's not in your $PATH variable).

Comment: No g++ is installed.check above comment

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all.

You don't have `g++` installed or

You have it installed but it is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: No g++ is installed.check above comment

Answer (score 0):

`g++ not found` indicates that your system can not find the executable file `g++`.

Ensure that your system knows where to search for `g++`.

On windows, this is done via the [environment variable "path"](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm).

Comment: No g++ is installed, this command is in makefile...and when i tried g++ without using makefile it worked.... below is my makefile         all:FINAL
 
 
FINAL : ${PATH}/first.o  final.o
        g++ -o FINAL ${PATH}/first.o final.o
 
final.o : final.cpp
        g++ -g -I${PATH} -I./ -c final.cpp
 
clean:
        rm *.o
        rm FINAL
~

Comment: May you paste your Makefile as code by editing your first post please? Since format is important that would be better. Thx

Comment: I have run same command on the shell prompt and it is working fine. :-(

Comment: One thing you can do is put the following in the rule where you are executing the g++ command before the g++ command itself... **echo $PATH**. This should tell you the PATH that the make is using when executing g++. Make sure g++ is in the displayed PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Add the g++ path in $PATH   export PATH=$PATH:g++Path